# Разбор URL адреса JS

Tags: javascript, url

Есть 2 фильтра в виде селектов,при выборе jsom передаю в URL параметры.

```
введите сюда код
```

http://timelate/stuff?dep-id=158

Чем можно парсить урл в JS чтобы при выборе второго фильтра параметр конкатенировался в первому,то есть

http://timelate/stuff?dep-id=158&date=2016-02-19

Ну при изменении одного из них чтобы значения менялись а все остальные параметры оставались!

```
$('#dep-filter').change(function(){
        $id = $(this).val();
        location.href = '/stuff?dep-id=' + $id;
    });

    $('#month-filter').change(function(){
        $date = $(this).val();
        location.href = '/stuff?month=' + $date;
    });
```

Comment: я ничего не понял, но для парсинга URL, обычно используются регулярные выражения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например так

```js
$(function() {
  var array = [];
  var server = 'http://timelate/stuff?';
  var url;

  $('#dep-filter').change(function() {
    array[0] = ('id=' + $(this).val());
    url = server + array.join('&');
    $('#res').text(url);
  });

  $('#month-filter').change(function() {
    array[1] = ('date=' + $(this).val());
    url = server + array.join('&');
    $('#res').text(url);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="dep-id" id="dep-filter">
  <option value="35">35</option>
  <option value="44">44</option>
  <option value="546">546</option>
</select>
<select name="date" id="month-filter">
  <option value="2016-02-19">2016</option>
  <option value="2015-02-19">2015</option>
  <option value="2017-02-19">2017</option>
</select>

<div id="res"></div>
```

Comment: То что надо,спасибо!

Comment: Кстати вариант ваш не совсем подходит мне так как после выбора в селекте идет перегрузка страницы,поэтому элемент в массиве только из последнего селекта!

Comment: @quaresma89 элемент не из последнего селекта, а из выбранного селекта.